# Pyspark UDF getting error 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

Created the below function , when I run this I get this below error.

```
**UnboundLocalError: local variable 'date' referenced before assignment**.
```

then when I add date = None , like this

```
signals = []
result = []
dct1 = {}
date =None
```

Then I get this error `java.lang.nullpointerexception`. Why  is this happening and how can I resolve this?

```
def decode(deviceID,dbc_path,canfile = []):

    db = cantools.database.load_file(dbc_path)

    signals = []
    result = []
    dct1 = {}
    date =None
    
    for canSignal in canfile:
          canId = canSignal ['canId']
          canTime = canSignal['canTimeStamp']
          try:
              timestamp1 = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(canTime).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
              date = timestamp1.split('T')[0]
              time = timestamp1.split('T')[1]
              dict = db.decode_message(canSignal[0], canSignal[2])
          except Exception as e:
              tupl = ('FAIL-'+deviceID+'-{'+dbc_path+'}-'+str(canId),date,[])
              result.append(tupl)
          else:
              dict["PartitionKey"] = f"{date}-{deviceID}"
              rightJustCanId = str(canId).zfill(10)
              dict["RowKey"] = str(canTime)+rightJustCanId

              dict_str = str(dict)
              tupl = ('PASS',date,dict_str)
              result.append(tupl)         
    return result


decode_udf = udf(decode, schema)
```

Comment: Does this happen on the `tupl = ` line?

Comment: you will have more chance to find your answers if you can post the full stack trace